# SQL Query To Find Proceeding Records

Tags: sql

This is a hard question for me to verbalize. I'll do my best. This is my record set:

```
DealershipID          PlacementDealershipID
40309                 -1
787289                40309
787461                787289
787402                787461
787520                787402
```

You will notice that the top of the chain is ID 40309 that has a PlacementDealershipID of -1. If we start with ID 787520, the PlacementDealershipID goes "up" the chain, until we get to DealershipID 40309.

Desired results would look like this starting at DealershipID 787520.

```
Starting DealershipID ---->>> 787520
1 Level(s) Up ---->>> 787402
2 Level(s) Up ---->>> 787461
3 Level(s) Up ---->>> 787289
4 Level(s) Up ---->>> 40309
```

I want to print a list of DealershipID's in SQL in order of DealershipID from starting point to 40309. I have done this using a while loop and declared variables. (Code Below). Is there an easier way to do this with SQL built in functionality?

```
-- Loop and pull structure
set @PreceedingDealershipID = 999
set @LevelNumber = 1
set @ContinueLoop = 1
set @LoopCount = 0

-- Determin maximum level for this system
set @MaxLevel = 30
set @MaxLevel = coalesce(@MaxLevel,30)


PRINT N'Starting ID ---->>> ' + convert(varchar(40), @DealershipID); 

while (@ContinueLoop = 1 and @PreceedingDealershipID  <> -1 and @PreceedingDealershipID  <> 0)
begin

    set @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
    if (@LoopCount > @MaxLevel)
    begin
        raiserror('THERE IS A LOOP IN THE DATABASE! CANNOT CONTINUE!',15,15)
        return
    end

SELECT @PreceedingDealershipID = d.PlacementDealershipID
FROM Sponsorship as d WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE d.DealershipID = CASE WHEN @LevelNumber = 1 THEN @DealershipId ELSE @PreceedingDealershipID  END

if (@PreceedingDealershipID <> 0 and @PreceedingDealershipID <> -1)
    Begin
        PRINT N'Level ' + convert(varchar(40), @LevelNumber) + ' Next Level Up ---->>> ' + convert(varchar(40), @PreceedingDealershipID); 
        set @LevelNumber = @LevelNumber + 1
    End
end -- end main loop
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If we start at DealershipID 787520 the desired results would be 787520, 787402, 787461, 787289,  40309

Comment: I edited the question to add desired results.